# Mover div para outra div e atualizar banco de dados

Tags: php, jquery-ui

Possuo o seguinte jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3, #sortable4, #sortable5, #sortable6").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        receive: function( event, ui ){
            jQuery("#carregando").html('<div class="text-center"><span class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></span> carregando..</div>').delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
            setTimeout(function(){

                $.ajax({
                    url: '<? echo base_url("vendas/pipeline/ajax"); ?>',
                   success: function(data) {
                        $('.pipeline').html(data);
                   }
                });             
            }, 2000);           
        },
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

E o seguinte HTML com PHP

```
    <div class="pipeline" id="pipeline">
        <? $i=1; foreach($lista_negocios_dashboard as $valor){ ?>
        <div class="col-md-2 pipeline-base connectedSortable" id="sortable<?=$i;?>">
            <div class="pipeline-categoria text-right">
                <? echo $valor->set_setor; ?>
            </div>
            <? foreach($valor->negocios as $negocios){ ?>
            <div class="pipeline-negocio">
                <h5><a href="<? echo base_url()."vendas/pipeline/negocios/editar/".$negocios->neg_cod; ?>"><? echo $negocios->neg_nome; ?></a></h5>
                <p><? echo $negocios->neg_descricao; ?></p>
            </div>
            <? } ?>
        </div>
        <? $i++;} ?>
    </div>
```

Nisso, eu consigo mover uma div para uma outra div. Funcionando 100%.
Porém, eu preciso atualizar o banco de dados, com a categoria que eu passar por esta div nova. Eu preciso recuperar pelo jQuery - cod_categoria e o cod_negocio, e setar este negocio nesta nova categoria, que foi arrastada...

Comment: O cod_negocio e cod_categoria no seu código seriam $negocios->neg_cod e $negocios->neg_nome?

Comment: Código do negócio: neg_cod, cod da categoria (pipeline class) set_cod

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando JQuery sortable você pode adicionar um atributo update e a partir daí fazer as alterações no banco.

```
$("#foo").sortable({
    update: function(event, ui){
        // a posição do item reposicionado
        var indice = ui.item.index();
    }
});
```

O atributo CHANGE é chamado para qualquer alteração e um item, ja o atributo UPDATE é chamado somente no fim da ultima alteração feita. Vale lembrar que todos os items que foram alterados, não somente o selecionado, vão disparar este evento.

Como exemplo:

Cito um [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956039/jquery-sortable-change-event-element-position) já existente aqui no stack com o seguinte exemplo:

```
$(function() {
$('#sortable').sortable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
        var start_pos = ui.item.index();
        ui.item.data('start_pos', start_pos);
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        var start_pos = ui.item.data('start_pos');
        var index = ui.placeholder.index();
        if (start_pos < index) {
            $('#sortable li:nth-child(' + index + ')').addClass('highlights');
        } else {
            $('#sortable li:eq(' + (index + 1) + ')').addClass('highlights');
        }
    },
    update: function(event, ui) {
        $('#sortable li').removeClass('highlights');
    }
});
```

});

No exemplo ele usa dois atributos, change e update, como eu mencionei na minha resposta. No change, ele adiciona a classe css highlights, que altera o fundo do item para a cor amarela (sendo originalmente cinza) e no update ele remove esta classe (voltando a cor para a original). Com este link você pode [ver o exemplo na pratica](http://devilmaycode.altervista.org/jquery-sortable-change-event-element-position/) e entender quando cada um desses eventos sao disparados e entender qual o melhor momento de atualizar o seu banco de dados, você vera também que o evento é disparado para todos os items.

Comment: Você teria um exemplo prático pra eu conseguir entender melhor?

Comment: Posso sim, editei minha resposta.

Comment: Sim, mas de que forma eu consigo atualizar meu banco de dados, conforme os ids?

Comment: O melhor momento de atualizar o banco de dados, é a hora que ele chegou na div, ai sim, atualiza

Comment: Usa o console do navegador e adiciona o seguinte log no codigo console.log(ui.item); veja se você consegue acessar os dados de categoria e negocio.